# entity manager unstable behaviour

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

i have a one to many relation ship between account and accountCode class with cascade all cascade type. when i delete account sometime the account and all its account code is deleted and sometime an exception occur state that "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint (ACCOUNTCODE_accountId) ". the second case usually occur when i add(persist) a new account code then try to delete the account. i am using eclipse link with sql server and i can provide the classes and the facade if this explanation is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try @PrivateOwned?

ref: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_privateowned.htm

Comment: i will try it, i believe that the problem is related somehow to the cash of persistence context. since if i clear the em before the delete the delete will always succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a bidirectional one to many?  If so, check that you are maintaining both sides of the relationship, such as adding the new account code instance to accounts OneToOmany list as well as setting the manyToOne back reference as the JPA provider can only cascade the remove operation to references it knows about.

Comment: it is bidirectional and i am maintaining both sides of the relations